# Default node package version set fail to build but a modified one works

Tags: node.js, typescript, version

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/744)
This problem is related with newer version of ts-loader throwing error, all fix when you downgrade tsloader from version "^4.0.1" to "^3.5.0"

Im programming a test project with backpack+typescript and using the following commands to install node packages:

```
npm install -D jshint ts-loader typescript backpack-core copy-webpack-plugin nodemon  
npm install -S asciify
```

### What, after some modifications, result in the following package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myTestProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "learn",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./prd/main.js",
    "dev": "backpack dev",  
    "build": "backpack build"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "backpack-core": "^0.7.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "jshint": "^2.9.5",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.2",
    "ts-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "asciify": "^1.3.5"
  }
}
```

---

### But when building with `npm run build` im receiving the error:

```
> myTestProject@0.0.1 build /home/myUser/myProjectFolder/myTestProject
> backpack build

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors00:34:00

 error  in ./src/main.ts

Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'afterCompile' of undefined
    at successfulTypeScriptInstance (/home/myUser/myProjectFolder/myTestProject/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/instances.js:147:28)
    at Object.getTypeScriptInstance (/home/myUser/myProjectFolder/myTestProject/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/instances.js:48:12)
    at Object.loader (/home/myUser/myProjectFolder/myTestProject/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:16:41)

 @ multi ./src/main.ts


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myTestProject@0.0.1 build: `backpack build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the myTestProject@0.0.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/myUser/.npm/_logs/2018-01-01T01_01_01_010Z-debug.log
```

---

### To solve the problem i need reinstall deleting the node_modules folder and replacing the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myTestProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "learn",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./prd/main.js",
    "dev": "backpack dev",
    "build": "backpack build"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "backpack-core": "^0.5.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "jshint": "^2.9.5",
    "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/asciify": "^1.3.29",
    "asciify": "^1.3.5"
  }
}
```

---

The package nodemon was added to try solve but had no effect.
My problem is that i found this working set of package versions after a lot of work but it can happen in another scenarios and i will not have so many time to fix and even can have a total understanding of what is happening here.
The `npm list` output several problems.
Can anyone explain why it happens and if there some way to avoid this type of problems, i cant guess the working version to put on every package on every time i type a `npm install` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ts-loader` 4.0 has breaking changes in line with the `webpack` breaking changes. I suspect you're bumping on that. I advise using 3.5 for your workflow.

Comment: that's what helped me when running across "Cannot read property 'afterCompile' of undefined", thanks.